# Modifying `*` and `o` style tikz arrows so that they are centered at the end of line

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I would like to use tikz `*` and `o` arrows to indicate included/excluded
endpoints in plots of piecewise functions, like for example the following one:

[image: Sample plot]

However, it seems that `tikz` always aligns the "tip" of the arrow with the end
of the line, so that the code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[help lines] (-.1,-.1) grid (2.1,2.1);
   \draw[thick,-*] (0,1.5) -- (1,.5);
   \draw[thick,o-] (1,1.5) -- (2,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: tikz arrows (incorrect alignment)]

where I would like the circles to be vertically aligned on the grid line.

Is there a parameter or code I can modify to get the desired behavior?

Comment: This should be an option in tikz arrows!

Comment: A similar problem arises with the `|` and the `[`/`]` arrows (well, actually, all arrows are defined this way): [TikZ arrow tip is displaced](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are the `shorten <` and `shorten >` option which allow you to shorten the arrow length from the start and end of the line, respectively. It also accepts negative values which then extend the arrow head forwards:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=-3pt,shorten <=-3pt]
   \draw[help lines] (-.1,-.1) grid[step=.5] (2.1,2.1);
   \draw[thick,-*] (0,1.5) -- (1,.5);
   \draw[thick,o-] (1,1.5) -- (2,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `3pt` was just a lucky guess, but seems to be the correct value for this arrow heads.

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you, I somehow missed the `shorten >` option.

Comment: The exact value is `1.8pt+1.4\pgflinewidth` which is 2.92pt for a `thick` line.

Comment: @Luigi: Where did you get the information about the exact value?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner from the code of the arrowhead. The radius of the circle line included is `4.5\pgfutil@tempdima + 0.5\pgflinewidth` (see Jake's answer for the code), hence you have to move the center by this quantity taking into account that `thick` means `line width=0.8pt`.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to avoid having to guess the value for the `shorten <` key, you can define new arrow heads that will place the circles precisely at the specified coordinate:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{center*}{center*}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{centero}{centero}
{
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[help lines] (-.1,-.1) grid (2.1,2.1);
   \draw[thick,-center*] (0,1.5) -- (1,.5);
   \draw[thin,centero-] (1,1.5) -- (2,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's not as simple as you imagine.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry. The left extend is correct, but the right extend should simply be `4.5\pgfutil@tempdima` if you want the center of the circle at the end of the line (IMHO).

Comment: @Luigi: Yes, that seems right. Edited, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this is great!  I packaged it and placed it on github: https://github.com/lahvak/intervalarrows

Answer (score 2):

With the newer `arrows.meta` library, this can be achieved by setting the `sep` to the negative of half the arrow tip's length. Since the [default value for the length](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex#L1219) of the  `Circle` arrow tip is

```
length  = +2.39365pt +3.191538
```

we'll be using

```
Circle[sep=-1.196825pt -1.595769]
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  */.tip={Circle[sep=-1.196825pt -1.595769]},
  o/.tip={Circle[sep=-1.196825pt -1.595769, open]},
]
   \draw[help lines] (-.1,-.1) grid (2.1,2.1);
   \draw[thick, -*] (0,1.5) -- (1,.5);
   \draw[thick, o-] (1,1.5) -- (2,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]