# improve a graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code for a figure.
I'm not satisfied with the result, in particular "the bullet".
How improve this figure ?
Thanks

```
  \def\xmin{-5}\def\xmax{5}
  \def\ymin{-1.5}\def\ymax{1.5}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[dotted,step=1] (\xmin,\ymin) grid (\xmax,\ymax);
    \draw[thick, ->] (\xmin,0)--(\xmax,0);
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,\ymin)--(0,\ymax);
    \clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
    \foreach \i in {-2,...,2}{
      \draw[very thick, *-(] (2*\i-1,-.5)--(2*\i+1,.5);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: What's not looking good? Maybe you're interested in [Q111051](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051) and [Q11871](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656241).

Comment: Try this for the arrows: \draw[cyan,line width=3pt, latex-] (2*\i-1,-.5)--(2*\i+1,.5);